# org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter not found error

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

After updating from Grails 2.3.10 to 2.3.11 and updating the path variable to

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/Applications/grails/grails-2.3.11
```

When I run: grails I get the following error:

```
Error: Main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter could not be found
```

Comment: have you tried to use GVM (http://gvmtool.net/) instead of installing Grails manually?

Comment: @saw303 I don't use GVM. I know that you have to copy something to make it work but I don't know what

Comment: +1 on using gvm. It will take care of updating grails home and the path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution. If you go to the grails/bin folder and run grails from the command line you can close the console afterwards and when you open the console again the problem will be fixed.

Comment: It is because the default version of grails is incorrectly set. This makes sure that all the dependencies grails needs like `spingloaded-core` are there.

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

Make sure you have environment variable set correctly.

1. Go to grails/bin folder `$cd /Applications/grails/grails-2.3.11/bin`
2. Then run grails from command line `$./grails`

When you run this command, necessary files for your grails will be downloaded.

3. Close your terminal
4. Now check your grails version from terminal `$grails -version`

There won't be any errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably still running grails 2.3.10.

You have to update `GRAILS_HOME` and you also have to update your path to use the new grails version, i.e. your path must include `$GRAILS_HOME/bin`.

Comment: That is what I did. You haven't read my question I wrote the new export Path in the question.

Comment: your question does not mention that you have updated the PATH variable... anyway, if you did I don't know what could be wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question and answers seems to be out-of-date. I have encountered the same problem but it has been fixed by replying the discussion [here](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/397). The easiest way to resolve the issue is to run the following command:

`chmod +x .sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh`

which helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `gvm` to install your version then use it to manage your versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Grails installed with GVM, and I've also run into this issue after updating environment variables in the profile and sourcing in the new changes. I was able to fix the problem simply by closing and reopening the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your jdk version. 
I was using jdk1.8.0_11 and it resolved with jdk1.8.0_45.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below commands: 
1. To set path to contain jdk 1.8.0_144 bin folder & Grails bin folder.
2. Set JAVA_HOME  to jdk1.8.0_144
3. set GRAILS_HOME to Grails-2.4.3 folder.

And it worked !!!